# Cant change local admin password via Powershell

Tags: powershell, change-password

I build a script to change to local admin password of some servers which i get out of the ad.
The script runs fine so far, but for a certain reason, on the local machine (where the password should also be changed) it runs into an error.

The only error message is "permisson denied", meanwhile running the script from another server against said machine works fine.

So everytime on the local server the password change is denied.

The executing and failing code part:

```
$user = [adsi]"WinNT://$Server/$($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Username),user";
$user.SetPassword($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password);
$user.SetInfo();
Write-Host "Password changed"
```

I cant use the cmdlet `Set-LocalUser` as its a WinServer 2012R2 without the module `Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` or even nuget.

Comment: which user do you use to execute the script ? Which permissions do this user have ?

Is it a opportunity to import the Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts Module? This should work also with 2012R2

Have you consider using net user [username] [password] to change the passwort ? net user does also work in a powershell commandline

Comment: The script is executed with my admin credentials, on Server A as on Server B. On this server i dont have the possibilty to import the module, is restriced by GPOs aswell.

i havent used net user until, definitly testing that.

Comment: Tested net user, Systemerror 5, permission denied.

Comment: mhh okay...maybe this is the root cause of your issue. You are missing necessary permission or some Policy is restricting your operation. For net user as well as for your original solution. It is difficult to give you advice if we are not able to take a look into you AD. But maybe GPOs such as "Network access: Restrict clients allowed to make remote calls to SAM" might restrict your operations.

Comment: The thing is, it inly doesnt work on the local user of the same user. So if i Change PW A on Server A, it doesnt work, if i change PW A from Server B it works.

Comment: Did you run your script with elevated privileges when executed locally? (Run as Admin)

Comment: Actually not, as a .bat file starts powershell with set-executionpolicy and afterwards executing the scriptfile.

But i will test it manually.

Comment: it workes if the shell is run as administrator, but can someone explain to me why it works remotly without "run as administrator" and for local you need it to run as administrator. seems kinda like a security leak to me then.